# Minimizing a quadratic form: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 \ iterations

Tags: precision-and-accuracy, mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimize this type of quadratic form:

```
expr = (-0.1 x1 + x2 + 1.2 x3 + x4 - x5)^2 + (x1 + 1.2 x2 + x3 - x4 - 
    0.1 x5)^2 + (1.2 x1 + x2 - x3 - 0.1 x4 + x5)^2 + (-x1 - 0.1 x2 + 
    x3 + 1.2 x4 + x5)^2 + (x1 - x2 - 0.1 x3 + x4 + 1.2 x5)^2
```

where x1,...,x5 are integers not simulteneously zero. Then I performed

```
Minimize[expr, 
 x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 != 0, {x1, x2, x3, x4, 
  x5}, Integers]
```

which apparently yields a solution `{4.45, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> -1, x5 -> 0}}`, but with the warning '*NMinimize::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or precision within 100 iterations*.'

Does this mean that the solution is not *actually* a solution? What is the meaning behind the warning? I can only find information related to 'NMinimize' (in which I believe 'Minimize' is based).

Comment: `expr = (-0.1 x1 + x2 + 1.2 x3 + x4 - x5)^2 + (x1 + 1.2 x2 + x3 - x4 - 
      0.1 x5)^2 + (1.2 x1 + x2 - x3 - 0.1 x4 + x5)^2 + (-x1 - 0.1 x2 +
       x3 + 1.2 x4 + x5)^2 + (x1 - x2 - 0.1 x3 + x4 + 1.2 x5)^2;
Minimize[{expr, {x1, x2, x3, x3, x5} != {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}, {x1, x2, x3,
    x4, x5} ∈ Integers, Method -> "DifferentialEvolution"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use arbitrary precision rather than machine precision

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Version

(* "12.3.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)" *)

expr = (-0.1 x1 + x2 + 1.2 x3 + x4 - x5)^2 + (x1 + 1.2 x2 + x3 - x4 - 
       0.1 x5)^2 + (1.2 x1 + x2 - x3 - 0.1 x4 + x5)^2 + (-x1 - 0.1 x2 + x3 + 
       1.2 x4 + x5)^2 + (x1 - x2 - 0.1 x3 + x4 + 1.2 x5)^2 // 
   SetPrecision[#, 10] &;

Minimize[{expr, x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 != 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, 
  x5}, Integers]

(* {4.450000000, {x1 -> 0, x2 -> 0, x3 -> 0, x4 -> 0, x5 -> 1}} *)
```

Comment: Thank you. Alternatively, can I do something like ```Minimize[{SetPrecision[expr,9], x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2 + x4^2 + x5^2 != 0}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, 
  x5}, Integers] ``` instead? It seems to work better when I minimize similar quadratic forms but with more variables. Or does this interfere with the solution somehow?

Comment: For this problem, it doesn't matter whether you set the precision separately or as part of the definition of `expr` as long as `Minimize` is not working with machine precision.